# Switch positions of startyear and endyear in moderntimeline

Tags: formatting, moderntimeline

How can I switch in package `moderntimeline` the positions of `startyear` and `endyear` without breaking the layout?

Would be nice to have the `startyear` below and the `endyear` on top.

I'd like to simply change 2010 with 2007 in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Can you please compose a simple, minimal and complete document showing what exactly do you want to change?

Comment: Hope this screenshot is enough? Didn't think that a minimal or complete document will help to solve the problem!?

Comment: @Megachip A MWE might not help to actually find the solution (although in some cases it actually does), but it certainly saves time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can produce the desired result by setting `\tlwidth`, `\tltextstart`, and `\tltextend` appropriately, as the following simple example shows:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage[firstyear=1999,lastyear=2012]{moderntimeline}

\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}
\tlwidth{-2pt}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\tlcventry[cyan!60!black]{2007}{2010}{test}{test}{test}{}{test}

\tldatecventry[brown]{2011}{test}{}{test}{test}{}{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the above solution the bars are below the timeline; to keep the bars above the timeline, instead of changing `\tlwidth` to a negative value, one can change the value for `\tl@textstartabove`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage[firstyear=1999,lastyear=2012]{moderntimeline}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}
\makeatother

\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\tlcventry[cyan!60!black]{2007}{2010}{test}{test}{test}{}{test}

\tldatecventry[brown]{2011}{test}{}{test}{test}{}{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfekt, excactly what i want. Thank you very very much. Possible this could add to moderntimeline documentation!?

Comment: @Megachip You're welcome. I will talk about this with the package creator. Please don't forget to accept the answer (accepting and up-voting are two different actions) if you consider that it solved your problem. In case of doubt please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: I've got a little problem with this solution, possible you could help me again and add it to the solution: see [link](http://www.abload.de/img/tllabel5ps66.png). The \tldatelabelcventry did not work proper anymore. \tllabelcventry works fine.

Comment: @Megachip I gladly will hel you, but I need to see some sample complete code (similar to the one in my answer) illustrating the problem. Please upload this sample code elsewhere and provide a link.

Comment: Sorry: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83530/correct-alignment-of-tldatelabelcventry-to-the-text