# moderntimeline: alignment of text on start and end of bars

Tags: moderntimeline

Again some problems with moderntimeline:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage[firstyear=1999,lastyear=2012]{moderntimeline}
```

\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}
\renewcommand{\tldatelabelcventry}[8][color1]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{\tl@lastyear}
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#2-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline]{
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \fill [#1] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,yshift=11pt] {#3}
        node {$\bullet$};
   }
}
{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}
}
\makeatother

\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\tlcventry[cyan!60!black]{2007}{2010}{test}{test}{test}{}{test}
\tllabelcventry[cyan!60!black]{2007}{2010}{Test}{test}{test}{test}{}{test}
\tlmaxdates{2008}{2012}
\tldatelabelcventry{2008}{Okt. 2008}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tldatelabelcventry{2012}{Okt. 2012}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tldatecventry[brown]{2011}{test}{}{test}{test}{}{test}

\end{document}

Produce:
[image]

Would be nice to have:
[image]

Problem also exists with original moderntimeline in a similar way:
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the implementation (probably of `\tldatelabelcventry`) in `moderntimeline.sty`; the second entry in the following example is shifted to the left:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage[firstyear=1999,lastyear=2012]{moderntimeline}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\tldatelabelcventry{2008}{Okt. 2008}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tlmaxdates{2008}{2012}
\tldatelabelcventry{2008}{Okt. 2008}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tldatelabelcventry{2012}{Okt. 2012}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a proper bounding box in the definition solves the problem with the alignment (but the labels overlap with the following text):

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage[firstyear=1999,lastyear=2012]{moderntimeline}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tldatelabelcventry}[8][color1]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{\tl@lastyear}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#2-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline]{%
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \fill [#1] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear] {#3}
        node {$\bullet$};
   }
}
{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}
}
\makeatother


\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\tldatelabelcventry{2008}{Okt. 2008}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tlmaxdates{2008}{2012}
\tldatelabelcventry{2008}{Okt. 2008}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tldatelabelcventry{2012}{Okt. 2012}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the code in the original question, besides adding a proper bounding box, some work with the position of the labels will have to be done:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage[firstyear=1999,lastyear=2012]{moderntimeline}


\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}
\renewcommand{\tldatelabelcventry}[8][color1]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{\tl@lastyear}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#2-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline]{%
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \fill [#1] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,yshift=5pt,anchor=east] {#3}
        node {$\bullet$};
   }
}
{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}
}
\makeatother
%
\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\tlcventry[cyan!60!black]{2007}{2010}{test}{test}{test}{}{test}
\tllabelcventry[cyan!60!black]{2007}{2010}{Test}{test}{test}{test}{}{test}
\tlmaxdates{2008}{2012}
\tldatelabelcventry{2008}{Okt. 2008}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tldatelabelcventry{2012}{Okt. 2012}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tldatecventry[brown]{2011}{test}{}{test}{test}{}{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, to get the desired alignment, one can produce a command similar to  `\tldatelabelcventry` but with another optional argument, allowing to specify the anchor for the label; this can be easily done with the help of the `xparse` package:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[firstyear=1999,lastyear=2012]{moderntimeline}


\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}
\NewDocumentCommand\tldatelabelcventryn{O{center}O{color1}mmmmmmm}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{\tl@lastyear}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#3-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline]{%
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \fill [#2] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,yshift=5pt,anchor=#1] {#4}
        node {$\bullet$};
   }
}
{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}
}
\makeatother
%
\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\tlcventry[cyan!60!black]{2007}{2010}{test}{test}{test}{}{test}
\tllabelcventry[cyan!60!black]{2007}{2010}{Test}{test}{test}{test}{}{test}
\tlmaxdates{2008}{2012}
\tldatelabelcventryn[west]{2008}{Okt. 2008}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tldatelabelcventryn[center][red!70!black]{2010}{Okt. 2010}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tldatelabelcventryn[east]{2012}{Okt. 2012}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}
\tldatecventry[brown]{2011}{test}{}{test}{test}{}{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you've rescued my life, again... thx a lot

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina This solution is pretty sweet. thanks also from me. but to get this perfect, there are still one thing annoying me: in your last example, the blue '2010' seems to be further away from the blue bar than the blue '2007' is. can the '2010' be moved toward the bar, so that the '2007' and the '2010' are equidistant to the blue bar ?

Answer (score 4):

quick workaround to implement is to set before and after each entry the anchor of the labels

```
%set the anchor as you prefer
\tltextstart[south east]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[north west]{\scriptsize} 
%--------

\tldatelabelcventry{2008}{Okt. 2008}{Test}{}{}{}{}{}

%------
%set it back as default
\tltextstart[south]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[north]{\scriptsize}
```